# MVC Ajax.BeginForm on Partial View ejecute function on Parent View update Parent View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, ajax.beginform

I am doing  MVC App. I have a View that call a Partial View as DialogPopUp.

That View execute a `@Ajax.BeginForm`. On Success it calls a javascript function defined in `Parent View` becouse there are not allow javascript un PartialView.
That function makes `<div hiddden>` visible, and viceversa.

```
 $(".hidden").toggleClass("hidden visible");
```

the problem I found, that I have `<div hiddden>` also in Parent View. So, when function is called, is works on both divs...(in Parent and in PartialView).

Is there a way that it is ejecuted only in PartialView?

Comment: use an Id selector ?

Comment: do you mind showing me how you call the javascript function in OnSuccess? i have a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406224/datatable-with-bootstrap-in-partial-view-using-ajax-begin-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your partial view contents in a div:

```
<div class="myPartialWrapper">
    ... your partial markup comes here
</div>
```

and then adapt your selector:

```
$(".myPartialWrapper .hidden").toggleClass("hidden visible");
```